# Angular 2: How to fetch data and return single values?

Tags: angular

A Accountpage should return Data to the logged in user. I've got following code:

**http.get.service.ts**

```
getUserData() {
      const token = this.currentUser.token;

      const body = JSON.stringify({token: token});
      return this.http.post('https://test.com/src/getuserdata', body)
        .map((response: Response) => {
          const data = response.json();
          const returnArray = [];
          for (let key in data) {
            returnArray.push(data[key]);
          }
          return returnArray;
        });
    }
```

The Output of the called JSON File is:

```
{
"email":"test@test.com","lastname":"Grimes"
}
```

**account.component.ts**

```
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

  userData: any = [];

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.getUserData()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.userData = data;
        }
      );
  }

}
```

The response of ngOnInit is "test@test.com, Grimes"

**account.component.html**

```
...
<div class="n-r-m-e" [innerText]="userData.email">
<div class="n-r-m-e-v" [innerText]="userData.lastname">
...
```

The div-tags return "undefinded". How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The response is asynchronous, so view is rendered before data has been retrieved.

You could solve this in a couple of ways. Either use the [**Safe Navigation Operator**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator), which will safeguard null values:

```html
<div class="n-r-m-e" [innerText]="userData?.email"></div>
<div class="n-r-m-e-v" [innerText]="userData?.lastname"></div>
```

Or you could wrap your div's inside an `*ngIf` that won't render that part of the template unless there is values in `userData`

```html
<div *ngIf="userData">
  <div class="n-r-m-e" [innerText]="userData.email"></div>
  <div class="n-r-m-e-v" [innerText]="userData.lastname"></div>
</div>
```

Also you could initialize the `userData` object, so that it will not be undefined.

Comment: That <thing>?.<property> notation has just allowed me to fix something I've been struggling with for hours.

Answer (score 0):

The reason userData is undefined is because the fetch for the data is async and will not be available when the template is originally rendered.

To pass data into your template from an async operation you need to make use of observables and the async pipe.

Component: 
`userData: Observable<any>;`

Template: 
`<account-component [userData]='userData | async'></account-component>`

It would also be a good idea to make a model for the data that you are passing into the template so that you don't need to use `Observable<any>` and can instead use something like `Observable<User>`

Comment: When i use `userData: Observable<any>;` i get get the error `Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User>'`

Comment: Ok, are you defining a model for the data coming back from the server? If so, you will need to have the server return a User object. Try setting the type to any to see if you can get the data to come through the pipe and then define the model after to typesafe it.